# pandas split timeseries in groups

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df['a'] = np.random.choice(range(0,100), 200)
>>> df['b'] = np.random.choice([0,1], 200)
>>> df.head()
    a  b
0  69  1
1  49  1
2  79  1
3  88  0
4  57  0
>>>
```

Some of the variables (in this example `'a'`) have a lot of unique values.

I would like to replace `'a'` with `a2` where `a2` has 5 unique values. In other words I want to define 5 groups and assign to each value of `a` one of the group.

For example `a2=1` if `0<=df['a']<20` and `a2=2` if `20<=df['a']<40` and so on.

Note: 
I used group of size `20` because `100/5 = 20`

How can I do that using `numpy` or  `pandas` or something else?

EDIT:
Possible solution

```
def group_array(a):
    a = a - a.min()
    a = 100 * a/a.max()
    a = (a.apply(int)//20)+1
    return a
```

Comment: `a2 = (df['a']//20)+1`

Comment: @Anmol_uppal What if 'a' is an array of double?

Comment: as per your given example you haven't mentioned about floating values, However , you can always use `a2 = (int(df['a'])//20)+1`

Comment: I am afraid that this does not work in case the values of `'a'` are in `[0,1]`

Comment: No it works fine I guess, it is producing `1` in [0, 1] is that what you required ?

Comment: No I was expecting partition like `[0, 0.2)-->1`, `[0.2, 0.4)-->2` and so on.   Basically I want to split an arbitrary sequence in 5 groups. (I am sorry. I did not pick the best example in the question)

Comment: simply multiply the number by 100 to scale it in the range(1, 100), and then apply the same algo , however you can play with numbers and find out your own way of doing the same.

Comment: Perfect! I have included a possible solution. Despite that I am sure that there is a numpy function to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.cut.html) to categorize the values in `df['a']`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[69,49,79,88,57], 'b':[1,1,1,0,0]})
df['a2'] = pd.cut(df['a'], bins=range(0,101,20), labels=range(1,6), )
print(df)
```

yields

```
    a  b a2
0  69  1  4
1  49  1  3
2  79  1  4
3  88  0  5
4  57  0  3
```